# Jquery Replace table row in JQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, row

I have a partial view "taskrow" that will return a table row, I am using this to show rows in tables as soon as they have been updated. I need to replace the row with class "tasks" and replace it with the row that is loaded, but am struggling with the syntax. I believe the code below is inserting a tr into a tr. I have tried for ages to use a combination of replaceWith and load() but have not managed to get this working. Could someone help me with this?

```
$(elem).parent().find("tr.tasks").load("@Url.Action("TaskRow", "Task")", { "id": id});
```

Comment: the button that is clicked to call the function containing the jquery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need something like this instead:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("TaskRow", "Task")', {'id': id}, function(data) {
    $(elem).closest('table').find('tr.tasks').replaceWith(data);
});
```

Comment: yeh i thought something like that might be the answer. But if so, how would i assign the .load(.. part of my code to the data variable? It has to be chained to something right, the .load() function?

Comment: You want to replace a table row, so `.load` isn't what you need. By using `$.get` you can employ a callback function that adds the data to the DOM however you like.

Answer (score 15):

```
var newRow = '<tr><td>blahh blah</td><td>blah...</td></tr>';
$('#tempID').replaceWith(newRow);
```